# Mina - HTTP Proxy – what is AbstractHttpLogicHandler for?

Tags: java, http, proxy, apache-mina

I am currently working on building a simple HTTP proxy using Apache Mina, in particular org.apache.mina.proxy, and I have a few questions about how to use some of the components.

- How do I extract the future address from an incoming HTTP request?   I
  can see how to create a ProxyConnection given a URL, but I can't see how
  to extract this from an incoming request.   I have a feeling this leads
  to my next question:
- What is AbstractHttpLogicHandler for?   I see it has a subclass, HttpSmartProxyHandler, but I am not sure if and how to use it.
- Is there an example somewhere that I could look at?   I've been looking at http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/xref/org/apache/mina/example/proxy/ but it doesn't seem to answer my questions above.

Answer (score 1):

I think that classes in org.apache.mina.proxy are classes to add proxy in you HTTP request and not classes you can directly used to build your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

About your second point: `AbstractHttpLogicHandler` is an abstract class that decorates `AbstractProxyLogicHandler`

> "[`AbstractHttpLogicHandler`](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/proxy/handlers/http/AbstractHttpLogicHandler.html) provides HTTP request encoding/response
>   decoding functionality"

`HttpSmartProxyHandler` is a concrete class that extends `AbstractProxyLogicHandler`. 
This class fulfills its contract by handling a HTTP response from the proxy server (by implementing `handleResponse(final HttpProxyResponse response)`)